# Get checked row value id with jquery selector

Tags: jquery, selector

I try to put an ID value behind a radio checked element for each record. It works fine on VIEW side, but now I want to get this ID VIA JQuery selector and POST it on ajax. 
My HTML looks as following:

```
<td>
   <input type="radio" name="cursa_radio" id="cursa_radio" value="ticket_selected" route_value ="'.$data['route'][$i]['id'].'">
            '.$data['route'][$i]['departure_station'].' //actual td value
</td>
```

This is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({

    url: MyVariable.urlsite + "curse_interne/getInternalTicketPrice",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $("#first_step").serialize()
     + '&internal_route_id=' +   $("input[name='cursa_radio']:checked ").text('value')
     + '&' + $("#first_step").serialize(),
```

Note that url site is my contorller file and getInternalTicketPrice is my function that has only this:

```
$a = $this->input->post('internal_route_id');
```

On console I get:

```
string(15) "[object Object]"
```

Any idea how to return the actual value of `route_value ="'.$data['route'][$i]['id'].'"`? 
Thank you!

Comment: Use `.val()` not `.text('value')`. Also, you're appending the serialized form data twice

Comment: the same... i get string(15) "[object Object]"

Answer (score 1):

Solved!
Just modified the selector like this :

```
$("input[name='cursa_radio']:checked").attr("route_value")
```